# What does last dot in the file permission attribute mean?

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem

What does the last dot in the file permission attribute mean?

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 me me      4096 Dec 21 13:14 snap
drwxr-xr-x. 14 me docker  4096 Dec 21 15:50 work
          ^
          |--------- what does this dot means?
```

This is shown by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a 9p mounted partition.

```
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Mount:

```
/home/me/work on /home/me/work type 9p (rw,relatime,sync,dirsync,access=client,trans=virtio)
```

I never saw this dot before and don't see any documentation explaining it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102624/what-does-a-dot-after-the-file-permission-bits-mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `.` means an [SELinux ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). (`+` means a [general ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list#Filesystem_ACLs).)

Source, more info: [What does the dot mean at the end of `-rw-r--r--`? How do you set it with `chmod`? on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/230559/443564)

Answer (score 4):

> From `info coreutils 'ls invocation'` under Linux
>
> ```
> GNU `ls' uses a `.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
>      security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
>      marked with a `+' character.
> ```

Reference: [The Meaning of the Dot - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594871)