# What does the final "+" mean after the user/group/others rwx permissions

Tags: chmod

How do you modify or eliminate the "+" symbol?

Example:

```
(directory)rwxr-x---+
```

Comment: Closely related: [What does last dot in the file permission attribute mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103608/what-does-last-dot-in-the-file-permission-attribute-mean/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does last dot in the file permission attribute mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103608/what-does-last-dot-in-the-file-permission-attribute-mean)

Comment: I'd rather leave both questions open.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The + indicates that the file has an Access Control List (ACL) with additional permissions.

- `getfacl {dir/file}` to get more info on what is set
- `setfacl -b {dir/file}` to remove ACL.

If you did not set this yourself please do not alter it. There probably is a setting there to prevent accidental deletion.